# -contains operator failing when it should not be

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am writing a script to create new AD users and doing a test to make sure an existing `displayname` is not found because `New-ADUser` will fail if one is found. Can someone help me understand why I might never get a true outcome from the following array list?

```
$ExistingDNs= Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=whateverOU' -Filter * -Property displayname | select displayname | Out-string
```

My goal is to load up all the existing `displayname`s in an OU and then compare this with a method in which I read a CSV file to create a `displayname`, but I can't seem to get it to return as true.

```
If ($ExistingDNs.DisplayName -contains $DisplayName)
```

I was told this should work, but when I try looking at the array it is empty? Only `$ExistingDSs` shows me the list visually in ISE, where I can see clearly that a name exists that is the same in my CSV file, but the match is never found and never comes back as true even though both are string values I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it is because you are using `Out-String` which breaks the object array that `select displayname` would have created. Currently your `$ExistingDNs` is a newline delimited string when you really want a string *array*.

```
$ExistingDNs = Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=whateverOU' -Filter * -Property displayname | select -ExpandProperty displayname
```

Also we use `-ExpandProperty` so you just end up with an array of strings. That way your conditional statement can be reduced to...

```
If ($ExistingDNs -contains $DisplayName)
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I think you are right about all of this except for the expanded displayname string doesn't seem to be delimited properly? So, I'm still getting False when I look at $ExistingDNs -contains $DisplayName. So, $ExistingDNs -expandproperty looks like this; Jones, Robert R, MD Reed, Paul Jones, Robin C, MD Smithmum, David S; and even though I'm looking for Reed, Paul (which is there) I think its not delimited properly and so -contains still fails? Could this be? Marking  your answer anyway...

Comment: Oddly enough, I rebooted and now this works as expected. Thanks Matt!